# How to SecureZeroMemory on a string_view?

Tags: c++, winapi

With this code:

```
std::string_view test = "kYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@";
SecureZeroMemory((void*)test.data(), test.length());
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
**vptr** was 0x7FF755084358.
```

With **std::string** i get no exception:

```
std::string test = "kYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@";
SecureZeroMemory((void*)test.data(), test.length());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot modify a string literal. Your string view is referring to a string literal.

Comment: What's SecureZeroMemory?

Comment: You should remove the casts, the `string` version will compile, the `string_view` one will not. That should be a clue.

Comment: Casting: The number one way to turn a known compiler error into an unknown runtime error. Use casts with caution.

Comment: @ALX23z [SecureZeroMemory function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa366877(v=vs.85))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string_view` is meant to be a **read-only** view into a string or memory buffer.  In your particular example, the `string_view` is pointing at a **read-only** string literal, so no amount of casting will make it writable.  But, if you do the following instead, then you *can* modify what a `string_view` points at, as long as it is being backed by a **writable** buffer:

```
char buffer[] = "kYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@";
std::string_view test = buffer;
SecureZeroMemory(const_cast<char*>(test.data()), test.length());
```

The `std::string` approach works (and BTW, the type-cast is not necessary) because the `string` makes a *copy* of the string literal data into its own internal **writable** memory buffer, which `data()` points at.

```
std::string test = "kYp3s6v9y$B&E)H@";
SecureZeroMemory(test.data(), test.length());
```